# Bootstrap-vue pagination nav not working as in the tutorial (refreshes when a page is clicked)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, pagination, bootstrap-vue

I implemented pagination for the gallery on my website following this [tutorial](https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/components/pagination-nav/). Problem is that unlike the pagination on the website linked above, my webpage refreshes after a new page number is clicked. That is not what I want to happen.

I want the webpage to stay in the same position, the same way it is on the tutorial. Here is a [fiddleJS](https://jsfiddle.net/sjhponze/1/) of how my gallery looks. Unfortunately, since the new pages lead to new URLs and the page refreshes, it leads to а 404 error on fiddleJS but I think it is sufficient to get the idea of what I have done so far.

Code from the fiddleJS:

```html
<div class="container text-center" id="app">
    <h1 class = "mb-3">Gallery</h1>
    <div class="img-gallery">
        <div v-show="currentPage == 1" class="row">
      <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" class="w-25">
        </div>
        <div v-show="currentPage == 2" class="row">
      <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" class="w-25">
      <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" class="w-25">
        </div>
        <div v-show="currentPage == 3" class="row">
      <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" class="w-25">
      <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" class="w-25">
      <img src="https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.jpg" class="w-25">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-2 mt-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <b-pagination-nav 
            v-model="currentPage"
            :link-gen="linkGen" 
            :number-of-pages=3 
            limit=7 
            use-router>
        </b-pagination-nav>
    </div>
</div><!-- container -->
<script>
    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      data: {
          currentPage: ''
      },
      methods: {
        linkGen(pageNum) {
          return `${pageNum}`
        }
      }
    })
</script>
```

Reading the tutorial, what I thought I should do is add use-router to the  tag, however, the addition of it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :::

```
methods: {
        linkGen(pageNum) {
          return pageNum;
        }
      }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/np62xjrq/

Comment: That prevents refreshing of the page, however, the URL address does not get updated after clicking a page.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `linkGen` function returns the full URL path, or return a vue-router `location` object (assuming you want to use a query string in the URL to change page):

```js
linkGen(page) {
  return {
    query {
     page: page
    }
  }
}
```